# JSON - RingCentral API - Trying to Fax Multiple Documents

Tags: json, api, ringcentral

I am trying to automate our faxing process, and got it working. However, I can't seem to figure out how to include multiple attachments. Here is what I have for my request URL and body:

URL: `https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/fax`

Body:

```
  {
    "control_type": "text",
    "label": "To",
    "name": "to",
    "type": "string",
    "optional": false
  },
  {
    "control_type": "text",
    "label": "Cover index",
    "name": "coverIndex",
    "type": "string",
    "optional": false
  },
  {
    "control_type": "text",
    "label": "Cover page text",
    "name": "coverPageText",
    "type": "string",
    "optional": false
  },
  {
    "name": "attachments",
    "type": "array",
    "optional": false,
    "binary_content": "false",
    "properties": []
  }
]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can send FAX with multiple attachments, just call the below function as many times as needed

**JavaScript example code:**

```
form = new FormData();

form.append('fax-document-1', require('fs').createReadStream('test-1.jpg'));

form.append('fax-document-2', require('fs').createReadStream('test-2.jpg'));
```

**Reference**:

- https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/messaging/fax/sending-faxes
- RingCentral Node.js SDK: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js can be installed via NPM `npm i @ringcentral/sdk`

Comment: Thanks Suyash. However, how would I convert it to the format above? I am using Workato, which is similar to Postman to write this out. Unfortunately, I cannot use any other language format aside from JSON as I posted above. Thanks!

Comment: @it_enthusiast2022 - I'm in the same boat, Did you get answer for this?